# How does CODE 8086 command LOOPW works?

Tags: binary, x86-16, instruction-set, ieee

How does this "LOOPW   0100" works ??

http://ece425web.groups.et.byu.net/stable/labs/8086InstructionSet.html

Answer (score 0):

Loop is a shortcut for

```
dec cx
jncxz label;
```

The w gives the operand size when using AT&T syntax (rather uncommon for x86). Since the "shortcut" is often faster than the loop instruction, loop is hardly used.